# Why I am getting a duplicate output in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, python-requests, syntax-error

I am trying the below code. But in the final output, I am getting repeated words. For example, if I input name as Jai, I will get JaiJai.

```
name = input ("Cheer: ")

for i in name:
    name +=i
    print('Give me a', i+",", i+"!")

print("What does it spell?")
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

```
for i in name:
  name +=i
```

for every character in a given word, add this character to the word.

Answer (score 0):

You adding up the value of `i` to the `name` variable
this line `name +=i` is redundant here :)

corrected code:

```
name = input ("Cheer: ")
for i in name:
    print('Give me a', i+",", i+"!")
print("What does it spell?")
print(name)
```